# Using C++ lib (PortAudio) in C# project. Need help understanding basics

Tags: c#, dllimport, portaudio

I **need** to use PortAudio library in C# project. Week of efforts doesn't seems to give any results. Still no luck adding this lib.

What I've tried so far:

- Adding compiled portaudio-sharp wrapper to my C# project and calling `Commons.Media.PortAudio.PortAudioInterop.Pa_GetDeviceCount()` from code - get `System.TypeInitializationException : DllNotFoundException`

Can someone give me vage walkthrough of process of adding this lib to empty project?

Best regards.

Comment: Please read the site help on how to ask a question and what topics you can ask about

Comment: You can google for "C# load unmanaged library", try it yourself and then come back if you still need some help. SO is not code writing service.

Comment: Ok, googling it.